# How do i make a user profile so that i will input the name, mail etc. and then it saves, so i can login

Tags: python, oop

```
class User:


    def __init__(self, username, email, date_of_birth, password):
        self.username = username
        self.email = email
        self.date_of_birth = date_of_birth
        self.password = password

    @staticmethod
    def login_or_register():
        userinput = input("login or register")


    def register(self):
        pass

    def login(self, login_reg):
        self.login_reg = login_reg
```

How do i make a user profile so that i will input the name, mail etc. and then it saves so i can login

Comment: do you want to store values runtime or in a file for future use

Comment: What do you mean, I'm a newbie.

Comment: so if you store the credentials runtime, when you close the program they disappear, you could store them in a file for future use though (woudnt recommend if you're that new).

Comment: I think that I want to finish this project and then I can improve it, so I make the base and continue from that.

Comment: Now my problem is how to store the values runtime?

Comment: that's simple enough, are you sure you want objects for each user? you could use a dictionary instead. by initiating the user object you are essentially just storing values, (which is perfectly fine) if you just want to login that doesnt need to be a method of that class

Comment: Sure, if it's possible to store the information about the user so that the data doesn't blend with other users!

Comment: So how should I do it?

Comment: ill write a small example using a dictionary to store credentials

Comment: Thank you! Appreciate your effort a lot!

Comment: no problem! do you want to hash passwords?

Comment: Yeah, if possible!

Comment: there ya go :) if you want any explanation im here to help. thanks for asking

Answer (score 0, accepted):

heres a really simple way to do it:

```
import hashlib

db = {}

hash = lambda x: hashlib.md5(x.encode()).hexdigest()

def register(user, password, mail):
    db[user] = {"password": hash(password), "mail": mail}

def login(user, password):
    if db[user]["password"] == hash(password):
        print("success!")
    else:
        print("fail")

register("ironkey", "password123", "example@example.com")

login("ironkey", "password")
login("ironkey", "password123")

# get credentials for the user ironkey
print(db["ironkey"])
```

```
fail
success!
{'password': '482c811da5d5b4bc6d497ffa98491e38', 'mail': 'example@example.com'}
```

Comment: Ay man your so kind, thank you and best of luck in the future!